# SP 2013 : Project Tasks : Export to MPP without MS Project Installed

Tags: sharepoint-server, ms-project

We are using **Share point 2013** *Project Tasks* object to create project tasks, so that  other users, like the management for example can see the **Gantt chart** of the projects.

Now I have got a requirement to export all the Project Tasks as MPP but we dont have *MS Project* installation anywhere.

How can we export a project tasks as MPP without MS Project installation?

Answer (score 0):

You need MS Project installed but it can be installed on any machine where the SharePoint sites are accessible. You create a VB Script ( Macros ) to automate the export process to export all the plans. As it is a one time job, you dont need to have a licensed version of MS Project, trail versions for 30 days should be good enough(I did the same way when i had this requirement).

If we dont have MS Project, than Power shell could be the only option, but Macros are alot easier.

Comment: My requirement of export is a recurring reqmt on regular basis. We dont have MS Project. Any pointer to using only powershell to export as MPP is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the VB Script to save all the project tasks to MPP files. 
There is a guide from Microsoft available to convert this VB script to Powershell code. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee221101.aspx

```
Sub SavingToMpp() ' Macro SavingToMpp

 Dim T As Task
    Dim fName As String

    For Each T In ActiveProject.Tasks
        fName = T.Name
        Application.FileOpenEx Name:="<>\" & fName, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
        Application.FileSaveAs Name:="E:\Mpp Files\" & fName, FormatID:="MSProject.MPP"
        Application.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave, CheckIn:=True
    Next T
End Sub
```

Comment: AS per the script provided, I understand tha this is from inside MS Project. But I dont have MS PRoject and hence I have to work only with Sharepoint 2013.